# How to finish sorting without creating new memories (with only std::swap())

Tags: sorting

The original problem could be complicated (in terms of scale and data structure), but here is the short version.
Suppose my data is `arr={2,3,1,4}` and I somehow already get the index of the sorted data, i.e., `idx={2,0,1,3}`. How can I get the results of `arr={1,2,3,4}` with only std::swap() (without creating new arr and copying)

I did some simple attempts but it seems can't match all the cases. I believe it should exist some named algorithms or something.